# Converting an ANSI C-String to UNICODE

Tags: c++, string, unicode, ansi

**Note:** I am trying to write my own function that performs this conversion

I understand that a `char` is 1 byte, while a `wchar_t` is 2 bytes.

So this is how a conversion would happen:

1) Input a text

```
Hello, world
```

2) Get the bytes of the string

```
48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21
```

3) Allocate memory twice the number of bytes

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

4) Fill a byte with the ANSI value, skipping one byte at a time

```
48 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00 6f 00 2c 00 20 00 77 00 6f 00 72 00 6c 00 64 00 21 00
```

**I have a couple of questions about this process:**

1) Can I simply cast an ANSI string to UNICODE and have it replicate the exact process above, or will it simply fill the first half of the bytes with the ANSI bytes and leave the rest to 0?

```
char a[] = { "Hello, world!" };
wchar_t* b = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(a);
```

2) Looking at the [MultiByteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) function, I see a `CodePage` argument and I wonder what it is. Isn't the conversion all the same (as I understand it and wrote it out above)? I thought the ASCII character codes were all the same everywhere, but this argument seems to say otherwise if I am understanding correctly from the fact it has values for Mac and Windows there.

Comment: Unrelated: `wchar_t` is usually 4 bytes. I think it's only Windows that uses 2 bytes for it.

Comment: What are the 4 bytes for, are there any UNICODE codes that occupy that much space? I also believe I heard a boolean is 8 bytes in C#, but I also do not understand why. But yes, I am working on a Windows system myself

Comment: The 4 bytes can be used to store the Unicode character as UTF-32. What Unicode Transformation Format are you aiming for?

Comment: @Hjkl  You need 32 bits if you want it large enough to represent any supported character code point in Unicode; I believe that was the reason. Even though in practice it's better to use e.g. UTF-8 over `char`s where you spread codepoints across multiple characters. Windows is "special" because it standardised on two-byte UTF-16 throughout the whole API; they just call it "Unicode", which is kind of ironic because historically Unicode _was_ inextricably what we now call UTF-16 (sort of) but they didn't move with the times so here we are...

Comment: I only ever heard about UTF, but don't actually understand what the difference is between UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 and what the point of either of them is, I only have a very basic understanding of ASCII and UNICODE

Comment: _"I also believe I heard a boolean is 8 bytes in C#"_ I find that highly unlikely, and can find no evidence to support it from a quick search.

Comment: @Hjkl Time to hit Wikipedia, then!

Comment: So if I wanted to support UTF-32, I would have to create my own wrapper for strings since wchar_t is only 2 bytes long and I need 4 bytes, and also I would not be able to print it with printf for example, correct?

Comment: You don't want to support UTF-32.

Comment: Why would that be a bad thing?

Comment: @Hjkl You are likely running on a Windows. It uses UTF-16LE (little endian) or rather UCS-2LE if I'm not mistaken. [UCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set)

Comment: @Hjkl C++11 adds standardized and portable `char16_t`/`std::u16string` for handling UTF-16 strings, and `char32_t`/`std::u32string` for handling UTF-32 strings. C++20 adds `char8_t`/`std::u8string` for handling UTF-8 strings (prior to C++20, you can use `char`/`std::string` for UTF-8).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Windows hasn't used UCS-2 since before Win2K.  Since then, Windows uses UTF-16 only. UCS-2 handles only codepoints in the BMP (U+0000..U+FFFF), UTF-16 handles codepoints up to U+10FFFF.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, ok, but it's UTF-16LE, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes. Windows is a little-endian OS, so it primarily uses UTF-16LE (though it does provide *some* APIs if you need to do work with UTF-16BE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought the ASCII character codes were all the same everywhere, but this argument seems to say otherwise if I am understanding correctly from the fact it has values for Mac and Windows there.

The ASCII codes are, yes, but the high bit of an "Extended ASCII" string (spoiler: there's no such thing) maps to any of a large number of *codepages*, all different encodings intended for use mostly in different geographic locales. The approach you've taken is fine for the simple, plain ASCII case, but it doesn't work in general, and `MultiByteToWideChar` knows this. It will re-encode properly from whatever codepage you're using, to what Windows confusingly calls "Unicode" (not "UNICODE"), which is actually more specifically the "UTF-16" encoding.

> Can I simply cast an ANSI string to UNICODE and have it replicate the exact process above, or will it simply fill the first half of the bytes with the ANSI bytes and leave the rest to 0?

No. A cast does not reencode things or change values. There you are just saying "I promise that `a` is a bunch of `wchar_t`s, even though it has type `char*` (it doesn't, it has array type, but close enough for today).

That code actually has undefined behaviour, if you use `b`, because you've broken aliasing rules (you can examine a `T` through a `char*`, but you can't treat a `char[]` as some `T` that you never created). But, if it didn't, you'd find that your "string" were now half the length, and more than likely an invalid UTF-16 sequence that would not render correctly anywhere.

> So if I wanted to support UTF-32, I would have to create my own wrapper for strings since wchar_t is only 2 bytes long and I need 4 bytes, and also I would not be able to print it with printf for example, correct?

Technically, sort of yes (though you'd use a library like *libicu* rather than rolling your own).

But, in reality, you don't want to use UTF-32. Working with the Windows API you're stuck with UTF-16, but other than that we generally prefer UTF-8 over `char`, which is nice and portable and flexible and good and nice. (You will again want a library for this though.)

It'd then be up to you as to where you perform the relevant conversions, and/or whether you have a switch that flips from UTF-8 to UTF-16 depending on the platform (like Windows's old `UNICODE` macro) or just run UTF-8 everywhere until you hit a Windows API boundary.

Or, if all your input is ASCII as you imply, then you don't really need to do anything other than what you are already: either keep your ASCII throughout the program but convert it to UTF-16 when using the Windows API, or use UTF-16 (and `wchar_t`s throughout your whole program and have no conversions. Make sure to use wide-char versions of your favourite functions, though (like `wprintf`) if you go down that route.

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed response, bro ;) I looked a bit more into codepages, turns out there are damn hundreds of them. I am wondering why that could be problem if all strings are isolated to my app (and I'm not sending them to a server or such), wouldn't it just be using the default codepage of Windows and I should have no issues?

Comment: Yeah, possibly, though it's impossible to say for sure without auditing your code, or at least having a strong idea of what strings go where and when and why. You still need to convert to UTF-16 for the Windows API though as that is what it expects.

Comment: For a very strong opinion on where to do your UTF-16 conversions, see http://utf8everywhere.org/.

Comment: @Hjkl Windows is customized for different countries and will have a different default codepage depending on where you are.  You will need to worry about it if you're reading or writing data to a window or a file.

Comment: @MarkRansom I read the OP's comment as meaning they weren't doing any of that, but you're right.

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting to do will only work for ASCII character codes in the range of 0..127.  Those characters have the same numeric values in Unicode, and thus can be copied as-is between `char` and `wchar_t` strings.

And no, you can't just `reinterpret_cast` the memory address of the `char` data to `wchar_t`*, you need to allocate a new `wchar_t` array and copy the values, eg:

```
char a[] = { "Hello, world!" };
wchar_t* b = new wchar_t[sizeof(a) * sizeof(wchar_t)];
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(a); ++i) {
    b[i] = static_cast<wchar_t>(a[i]);
}
...
delete[] b;
```

This type of copying would be better handled using `std::string` and `std::wstring` iterator-based constructors instead, eg:

```
std::string a = "Hello, world!";
std::wstring b(a.begin(), a.end());
...
```

However, beyond the ASCII range, you need to *convert* the data between `char` and `wchar_t` via charset/codepage lookups.  Different charsets/codepages encode Unicode characters in different ways.  `MultiByteToWideChar()` (and `WideCharToMultiByte()`) handle those conversion for you, using the codepage that you tell it to use.  There are also many 3rd party libraries that can also handle these conversions, such as ICONV, ICU, etc.  To an extent, even C++'s own `std::wstring_convert` and `std::wbuffer_convert` can, too (though they are deprecated in C++17 onwards).

For example, let's look at codepoint [U+20AC EURO SIGN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) (`€`):

- in a `wchar_t` string, it takes up a single `wchar_t` whose numeric value is `0x20AC`.
- in a UTF-8 encoded `char` string, it takes up 3 `char`s whose numeric values are `0xE2 0x82 0xAC`.
- in a Windows-1252 encoded `char` string, it takes up a single `char` whose numeric value is `0x80`.
- in a Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) encoded `char` string, the Euro sign doesn't even have a numeric value assigned!

So, a simple value copy will not suffice for non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Sad shit. Too bad people didn't agree on a single standard and theres 1000 codepages out there. I suppose the best way to go is just to use UNICODE alone, conversions are a pain in the ass\

Comment: @Hjkl They did, it just took a long time ;)

Comment: @Hjkl "*Too bad people didn't agree on a single standard*" - they did, it is called Unicode. "*theres 1000 codepages out there*" - exactly, which is why you should avoid writing code that has to deal with them, except where absolutely necessary. For instance, use Unicode only for your data inside your app, and convert the data to/from ANSI only at the boundaries where data leaves/enters your app.

Comment: @Hjkl yes Unicode is definitely the way forward.  Unfortunately even Unicode was slow in getting started, the reason Windows uses UTF-16 instead of UTF-32 is because they were an early adopter and nobody had anticipated the need for more than 16 bits yet.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers. There is quite a lot to know about this topic that seems simple enough at a first glance